# MS-Graph-SDK cannot add folder to Drive

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to add a folder to a drive in a SharePoint site. I have tried many examples yet I am always receiving a 500 Internal Server Error. I have allocated and consented to the permissions as stated are required by the ms docs for adding files to a drive: Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All

```
 var folder = new DriveItem
        {
            Name = "New Folder",
            Folder = new Folder(),
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior","fail"}
            },
        };
```

And here are just two examples of the queries I have tried executing:

```
await graphClient.Groups[groupId]
                 .Sites[siteId]
                 .Lists[listId]
                 .Drive
                 .Root
                 .ItemWithPath("/{Custom Parent Folder I want to add a folder to}")
                 .Children
                 .Request()
                 .AddAsync(folder);

await graphClient.Sites[siteId]
             .Drives[driveId]
             .Root
             .Children
             .Request()
             .AddAsync(folder);

await graphClient.Sites[siteId]
                 .Lists[listId]
                 .Drive
                 .Root
                 .Children
                 .Request()
                 .AddAsync(folder);
```

Whether trying to add the folder to a custom document library or the root 'Documents' still results in an invalid request. This is my first time using Graph and the SDK so I am likely missing something.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The second one worked correctly for me. What is the message you are getting in the error.

Comment: Returns a 500 Internal Server Error with an error message of Invalid request.The Id Keys I use I get from requests and so I cannot see what I am doing incorrectly

Comment: Please try to test it in [graph explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and see if it is working there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Frustratingly, I created a new app registration in azure and it worked.